# Jquery - slide element from list to another list animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I have two lists that contains the same type of elements, just resized.
I have the main list, containing `100x100` or so **imgages** and the second list is containing the same images, just has a `.resize` class on, which makes the `25x25`

What I want to do is, slide an element of the first list, to the second list, so while it slides, it also resizes itself till it matches inside the second list, and the second list will resort itself, and the first list too (This is similar to [stackoverflow chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) user avatars when someone joins.

This is how my thing looks like:

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/a2f67205664e3a47f92e488af1fac60d.png))</sub>

You can see the first list under My sites and the second list to the right of My sites.

```
        <section>
            <div id="sites-left">
                <span class="sites_title">My sites</span>
            </div>
            <div id="sites-right">
                <ul id="already_voted">
                    <li>
                        <img src="img/blabla.png" class="resize" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Available in 6 hours"/>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="img/blabla.png" class="resize" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="img/blabla.png" class="resize" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="img/blabla.png" class="resize" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="img/blabla.png" class="resize" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="line"></div>
        </section>
        <ul id="sites">
            <li class="site">
                <img src="img/blabla.png" />
            </li>
            <li class="site">
                <img src="img/blabla.png" />
            </li>
            <li class="site">
                <img src="img/blabla.png" />
            </li>
            <li class="site">
                <img src="img/blabla.png" />
            </li>
            <li class="site">
                <img src="img/blabla.png" class="selected"/>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

CSS:

```
#sites-left {
    float: left;
}

#sites-right {
    float: right;
}

.sites_title {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #e4b31e;

    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
}

.resize {
    width: 25px;
    height: auto;

    opacity: 0.5;
}

.resize:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

#already_voted {
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

#already_voted li {
    margin-left: 15px;
    display: inline;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    margin-top:10px;

    clear: both;
}

.site {
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 20px;

    margin-right: 3%;
}

.selected {
    border-bottom: 10px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

How can this be done? thank you for your assistance!

Comment: `How can this be done` is far too broad a question. What have you tried? What part is giving you problems. Creating a demo that includes enough css for the basics would also help

Comment: Hi can you provide us the css too

Comment: @charlietfl I know how to create basic animations with jQuery plugins, but no idea how can an element slide off into another container (list) with an animation.

Comment: @AnisBoukhris Added CSS.

Comment: I would start by getting `offset()` of target and current location , then you know where to animate to. In callback of animation insert new element to new list and remove from the first. try at least getting that part started in a demo in jsfiddle.net or other code sharing site

Comment: @charlietfl I got what you mean, would I need to set position to absolute of that element?

Comment: Might take a look at how some of the draggable/sortable plugins like jQueryUI work and use *placeholders* in list(s) while animating

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do something like

```js
var dstOffset = $('#target').offset();
var dstHeight = $('#target').height();
var dstWidth = $('#target').width();

$("#source").animate({
    "left": dstOffset.left, 
    "top": dstOffset.top,
    "height": dstHeight,
    "width": dstWidth
}, "slow");
```

```css
#source {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: yellow;
}

#target {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 200px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="source"></div>
<div id="target"></div>
```